# Function Calling and Defining with different number of arguments

Tags: c, function

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sum(int ,int);

int main()    
{
    sum(4,5,6);
    return 0;
}

void sum(int a,int b)
{
    printf("%d",a+b);
}
```

As function signature comprises of function name and parameters, so in above code snippet function calling and its definition are different signatures and must be error. But it is merely showing warning and displaying correct output and when I am writing definition before main function, it doesn't work and shows error. Why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling a prototype function with the wrong number of arguments. That's constraint violation ([6.5.2.2p2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p2)) and the behavior is undefined. A conforming compiler must diagnose a constraint violation, but it isn't obligated to fail the compilation. (My gcc, clang, and tcc all fail it, though.)

Comment: Can u please explain about this constraint violation in simple words .

Comment: @Shivanshu The link links to a paragraph in the standard about function calls. The paragraph is under a section labeled constraints. Constraints are rules violations of which must be diagnosed.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to call the method `sum` with 3 arguments. It only takes 2 arguments.

Comment: So they are of different signature and should display the error.But code is displaying correct answer.

Comment: @Shivanshu I read your question too fast perhaps. But it should fail no matter if the `sum` function is above or below the main function. Or it might mask another function you include in a header? As far as I know, stdio.h does not include a sum function accepting 3 arguments. See [here](https://ideone.com/HDDnkC) for testing your code online.